# How to return SERVFAIL and REFUSED codes using CAA Lookup?

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, ca, dnssec

I'm developing the validation of the CAA (Certification Authority Authorization) records for the SSL certificates issuance, according to RFC 6884.

I would like to know how to check the FQDNs 15, 16, 18 and 19, which are present in the CAA Test Suite (https://caatestsuite.com/). When I'm using Lookup(String domain, int Type.CAA) for the servfail, refused, and even the expired and missing.caatestsuite-dnssec.com domains, it is returned an empty list of CAA records. In addition, it is shown in my console an error message with the NXDOMAIN Rcode, instead of (p.e.) SERVFAIL Rcode.

I don't know how to resolve this problem, because when it is returned an empty list of CAA records, it means that all CAs are allowed to issue certificates for a given domain.

I would appreciate any help and I hope you have understood my point.
Thank you all.

Comment: I was not able to understand. What is "Lookup(String domain, int Type.CAA)" ? Where/How to do you do that?

Comment: Patrick Mevzek, there are several lookup constructors, but I'm using in particular the Lookup(java.lang.String name, int type). This constructor creates a Lookup object that will find DNS records of the given name (string) and type in the IN class.

We can find the right information here: http://www.dnsjava.org/doc/org/xbill/DNS/Lookup.html.

Comment: So you are saying that you are using Java `Lookup(java.lang.String name, int type)` on a query for which you expect SERVFAIL for example but instead you get positive reply with 0 CAA records? If that is so, first course of action would be to try the exact same query with another library/program from the same host to see if you get the same replies.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I've already tried that and I get the same replies. However, Lookup has the method getErrorString and when I use this, I get a SERVFAIL message for both servfail and refused domains. It is very intriguing, because the REFUSED code exists in the source code! Maybe just there's a bug on the FQDN implementation... I hope so!
Anyway, I thank you a lot for your precious time.

Comment: Try with another library. Like GetDNS. See its Java bindings here: https://github.com/getdnsapi/getdns-java-bindings

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I'm going to try with that! :D